# How can I migrate my likes of a link to another link?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, migrate

I have remade my site, but it contains different links with old site. 
How can I migrate likes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be an easy solution. Depending on what framework you're using (if any) you may have to change them all individually. If this ends up being the case you're going to want to use sed from the command line to replace all instance of the old URL with the new URL. If you're using a CMS you should be able to change the base URL from the administration panel. If you're URLs are stored in a database you can use MySQL's replace command to replace the old URL with the new.